# JPA EntityManager not initialized in struts2 and JBOSS 7.1

Tags: java, jpa, struts2, jboss7.x, cdi

I am starting struts2 based application with Jboss provided JPA libraries.
I have configured data-source in standalone.xml I can see from the jboss administration console that 
the datasource is created. and the presistence.xml files are read and processed.
But if I check the  EntityManager instance in Action Class. It always says null.

Here is my persistence.xml and Action class snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence


http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mysqlDS</jta-data-source>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Struts2 Action Class:

```
public class RegistrationAction extends  ActionSupport implements SessionAware,Preparable ,ModelDriven{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Object getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        if(em==null)
            System.out.println(" EM is null still..");
         //even Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("primary"); returning NULL

    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

}
```

Comment: A couple of suggestions, since I don't know the exact answer. Are you using container or bean managed persistence? If CMT then have you tried injecting entityManagerFactory instead of entityManager?

Comment: I am not using EJBs. does it applicable for web components?

Comment: yes, it does. Just as an initial suggestion, try injecting entityManagerFactory instead of entityManager. You can google about how to do that. If you get a different answer, try their approach first as I am not very sure about the value add of entityManagerFactory.

Comment: tried injecting EMF but still same issue. It is something to do with struts2 famework..because I wrote simple servlet and tried injecting EM and it works fine. It does not works if I go through strut2 dispatcher or something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions are managed by the **Struts Container**.

EntityManager is managed by **CDI Container**. You can Inject it in CDI Managed objects (EJBs in EJB Container, CDI managed beans, servlets, ecc...), but not in Actions.

You need to either use the [Struts2-CDI-Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/cdi-plugin.html) or to perform a lookup to get it. You should not even inject it in Actions BTW, it would be better to use a business component (for examle an EJB) and perform a lookup on that.

If not using the CDI Plugin (for example because using the Spring Plugin), the [CDIUtil.java](https://github.com/AdamBien/lightfish/blob/master/multilight/lightfish/src/main/java/org/lightfish/beanlocator/CdiUtil.java) by Rob Veldpaus is perfect for this.

Example EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEjb{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
    EntityManager em;

    public Foo find(long id){
        return em.find(Foo.class, id);
    }
}
```

Example Action:

```
public class RegistrationAction extends ActionSupport 
                             implements SessionAware,Preparable ,ModelDriven {

    public String execute(){
        MyEjb ejb = new CdiUtil().lookup(MyEjb.class);
        System.out.println(ejb.find(1L));
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /* your other stuff here */
}
```

Comment: great..but I have another issue. I tried saving the model using em.persit().. it says : JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)..  if I try to call em.getTransaction() is says EntityManager cannot use Transaction.. any suggestions?  I have @PersistenceContext(unitName="primary",type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION) in place already.

Comment: You need to either do this in an EJB (transaction is by default Container managed), or in a CDI component (by manually handling the transaction, or by using an @Interceptor), or if you want to do it in the view tier (Actions), you need to use the [OSIV (Open Session In View, with Hibernate) / OEMIV (Open Entity Manager In View, with JPA) *anti*-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26973725/1654265). I strongly suggest the EJB 3.1 way.

Comment: I am writting  a job portal for a company. I am thinking to switch to Tomcat7 -EclipseLink . I donot think I need EJBs and other services offered by Jboss for this.. what do you say? sorry this is off topic..

Comment: You can install [**Weld** (reference CDI implementation) or **OpenWebBeans** (Apache CDI implementation)](http://balusc.blogspot.it/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html) in Tomcat as described in BalusC's blog post, or simply use [TomEE (Tomcat on steroids)](http://tomee.apache.org/), I've never heard anyone talking bad of it, anywhere. If you want EclipseLink out of the box, you need [**TomEE PluME**](http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html)

Answer (score 2):

[CDI Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/docs/cdi-plugin.html) struts 2 plugin Worked for me.

pom.xml in included:

```
    <!-- Import the CDI API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-cdi-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SP1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then in my Action class:

```
public class SampleAction extends BaseAction{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Action(value="add")
public String add(){
    try{
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        ........
        em.merge(...);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
}
```