# Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); is not working in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I am trying to integrate hibernate and struts2. There is no error. But the session is not created at all.Following is my code.

**CustomerAction.java**

```
    public String addCustomer(Customer customer) throws Exception{

        //get hibernate session from the servlet context
        SessionFactory sessionFactory =
             (SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext()
                     .getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME);
        System.out.println("session factory accessed");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println("session created");

        //save it
        

        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Transaction begin");
        session.save(customer);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

**HibernateListener.java**

```
    public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener{

    private Configuration config;
    private SessionFactory factory;
    private String path = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static Class clazz = HibernateListener.class;

    public static final String KEY_NAME = clazz.getName();

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
      //
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

     try {
         SessionFactory sessionFactory =
                    new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            System.out.println("session factory created");

            //save the Hibernate session factory into serlvet context
            event.getServletContext().setAttribute(KEY_NAME, factory);
      } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

  <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="addCustomer"
    class="com.mkyong.customer.action.CustomerAction">
       <result name="success">WEB-INF/pages/customer.jsp</result>
    </action>

      </package>
</struts>
```

The code is not giving any error but no data is inserted in database.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to integrate Struts2 and hibernate directly via plugin. You can see the examples provided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32376934/573032) answer.

> In Struts2 there's unofficial plugin called Struts2 Full Hibernate
> Plugin or [struts2-s2hibernate](/questions/tagged/struts2-s2hibernate) that provides an integration with
> Hibernate. There're examples:
>
> - [Struts2 hibernate integration via s2hibernate plugin](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-hibernate-integration-1.html)
> - [Struts 2 + Hibernate integration with “Full Hibernate Plugin”](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hibernate-integration-with-full-hibernate-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks. But I took help of http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hibernate-integration-example/. And the above code is like this only.