# Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file: /WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.24.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

Below are the files,

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Struts2</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>   
  <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="action.MyAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

**MyAction.java**

```
package action;

public class MyAction {

    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("in execute method");
        return "success";
    }

}
```

However whenever I try to run the project ,I get the following error in the console

```
Nov 17, 2015 2:49:25 AM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/E:/Java_EE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.24.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5193)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/E:/Java_EE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.24.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:218)
    ... 20 more

Nov 17, 2015 2:49:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/E:/Java_EE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.24.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5193)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/E:/Java_EE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.24.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/E:/Java_EE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.24.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:218)
    ... 20 more

Nov 17, 2015 2:49:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

I have the jar file ***struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.24.1.jar*** in the libraries inspite of it I am getting these error.

I have spent hours searching to rectify this but have not found any solution. Any suggestions or answers will be helpful.

Comment: Just remove the gxp plugin. Life will smile at you then

Comment: A comment can sometimes be a life saver ;) .Big Thanks @Andrea Ligios

Comment: @Andrea The problem occured when I added all jars of Struts2 into the library. Does it mean we should only add some selected jars of Struts2 into our project . If yes ,then which jars?

Comment: It depends on your project's needs, but adding ALL the jars is wrong on principle. You should always add only what you need, because ***what is not there, cant' break*** :D In standard Struts2 projects however I'd add only the needed jars (struts2-core, freemarker, ognl, commons-lang3, ecc.. plus struts2-convention-plugin and struts2-json-plugin. If you are used to it, also struts2-jquery-plugin (or jquery-grid, or bootstrap-plugin, etcc) but they're not necessary. GXP is a 0.2 alpha project, that depends on other libraries, break often, is not mantained etc.. never use this kind of things :|

Comment: Also CDI plugin if using Java EE (and you should), or Spring plugin if using Spring. Don't use the full-hibernate plugin. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31557968/1654265